# When Pesach falls on Motzei Shabbos, should women make Havdallah?

Tags: halacha, minhag, women, passover-seder-hagada, havdalah

Although there are numerous customs, some have the custom that all present at the Seder - including women - recite Kiddush together.

On a year such as this, where *pesach* falls on *Motzei Shabbos*, what is the halacha regarding women? In general, the Rema (OC 296) rules that women do not make *havdallah* themselves, at least if there is a possibility to be *yotzei* from a man. What is the custom regarding women making *birchas havdallah* in Kiddush on *leil haseder*?

Is there any reason why one who during the rest of the year is stringent that women should not recite their own *havdallah* would allow women to recite it on *leil haseder*?

Answer (score 6):

R. Moshe Stern in [Be'er Moshe V:136](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=889&st=&pgnum=371&hilite=) writes that that a woman should not deviate from her regular custom when *seder* night falls on *motza'ei shabbat*, but instead should say *havdalah* as part of *kiddush*.

R. Menashe Klein in [Mishneh Halachot VIII:36](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1880&pgnum=50) writes that maybe it would be better for a woman reciting *kiddush* to listen to the *havdalah*-blessing and answer *amen*, rather than reciting it herself. However, it is also absolutely fine if she recites the whole *kiddush* including *havdalah* herself.

For an exhaustive treatment of this question, see R. Zvika Ryzman's [Ratz KaTzvi, Pesach - Shavuot 10](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48237&st=&pgnum=194).

Comment: Thank you for three great sources. Do you recall if any reasons are given to differentiate between regular Motze Shabbos and Pesach?

Comment: @chortkov2 I’m not sure. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

In Shmiras Shabbas Khilchasa 62: footnote 27 it discusses the issues of maybe havdala being a possible hefsek for a woman. First he mentions that the woman should hear kiddush and havdalah from a man and that would not be considered a hefesk. However ,he mentions that since women took on havdala as an obligation it is not a hefsek and they can do yaknahaz,and so he heard this from Rav Shlomo Zalman Aurbach. He does add though that she should not make birkas ha'aish.

Text:

[image]