# What do women who normally abstain from drinking havdalah wine drink do when the Seder falls out after Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, women, havdalah, four-cups-wine

There is a widespread custom that women do not drink from the wine used in the havdalah ceremony. When the seder falls out on motzei shabbat havdalah is incorporated into the kiddush, which women are obligated to drink from. Would this be a situation in which the obligation to drink overrides the custom to abstain? Do any halachic authorities address this issue?

Comment: There's no question the obligation to drink overrides any custom to abstain. The only question is if there is some trick the women can do to avoid having to override the custom (maybe hearing havdala from someone else separate form saying kiddush herself?)

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/121266/759

Comment: See [here](https://olamot.net/shiurim/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%95%D7%91-%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%96-%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8/), section 8 and on.

Comment: Also [here](https://tora-forum.co.il/threads/%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%96-%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D.18545/): כשזהו גם כוס של קידוש לא שייך האי טעמא

Answer (score 1):

The minhag is that women do drink from the wine in such a case. See sources below.

שבט הלוי (מבית לוי חי"ב עמ' נ"א סעי' ז') – "המנהג שהנשים שותות מכוס הקידוש אף שהבדילו עליו ג"כ".

ששכ"ה (פרק ס"ב סעי' ט"ז, הע' כ"ח) – "ואף על פי שהמנהג הוא שאין האשה שותה יין מכוס של הבדלה, וכדלעיל פרק ס סעיף לח, מכל מקום המנהג הוא שהנשים שותות מכוס זו של קידוש והבדלה יחד. [ספר 'שובע שמחות' דף קג]".

חוט שני (ח"ד ריש עמ' ק"י) – "לענין יקנה"ז אע"פ דהתם שותות היין ובהבדלה אינם שותות ...".

ילקוט יוסף (שבת ח"א עמ' תנ"ז אות ט"ו, קיצור שו"ע סי' רצ"ו סעי' ט"ו) – "ויום טוב שחל להיות במוצאי שבת, שמקדשין ומבדילין על הכוס ביחד, פשוט שמותר לאשה לטעום מכוס הקידוש, אף שאמרו עליו גם ברכת ההבדלה".

פסקי תשובות (דפו"ח, סי' רצ"ו סוף אות ח', הע' פ"ז) – "ולענין יום טוב שחל במוצאי שבת, נוהגים כל ישראל שנותנים לנשים ולשאר בני הבית לשתות מכוס הקידוש, הגם שגם הבדילו עליו, ואין פוצה פה ומצפצף. [כמבואר בשש"כ פס"ב סעי' ט"ז. ובשו"ת מגדנות אליהו (שם, בהערה) שעפ"י הטעם הנ"ל (הערה ע"ז) בשם הר צבי, יצטרכו לברך בעצמן בופה"ג, כי ענו 'אמן' על ברכות הנר וההבדלה]".